# Binding Image Width and Height

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I have a `ListViewItem` with an `Image` inside. When I try to bind the `Width` and `Height` of the image, the image doesn't appear but when I set the size manually in XAML code it works perfect.

Xaml Code:

```
<ListView x:Name="lstPerson" Visibility="Visible" Background="White" Foreground="Black">
   <ListView.View>
      <GridViewColumn>
         <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
               <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                  <Image x:Name="imgThumnailItem" Stretch="Fill" Height="130" Width="{Binding WidthSize}" Source="{Binding ThumbnailItem}"/>
               </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
         </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
      </GridViewColumn>                                    
      <GridViewColumn Width="100" Header="PC/Username" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding PcNameUserName}"/>
      <GridViewColumn Width="100" Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Namet}"/>
      <GridViewColumn Width="100" Header="Nachname" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Nachname}"/>
   </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

and my Code behind

```
// Preparing Image
var img = new BitmapImage();
img.BeginInit();
img.StreamSource = new MemoryStream(_thumbImage);
img.EndInit();

PersonList.Add(new MainFunctions {
   PcNameUserName = vorschauObj.PcNameUserName,
   Name = vorschauObj.Name,
   Nachname = Nachname,
   ThumbnailItem = img,
   WidthSize = 100,
   HeightSize = 100 
});

this.lstPersons.ItemSource = PersonList;
```

MainFunction.cs

```
public class MainFunctions 
    {

        public string PcNameUserName { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Nachname { get; set; }

        public double WidthSize { get; set; }

        public double HeightSize { get; set; }

        public BitmapImage ThumbnailItem {get;set;}
    }
```

Comment: And other fields, like `PcNameUserName` display fine?

Comment: Can we see the `MainFunctions` class?

Comment: The other fields are displayed fine without any problem.

Comment: I've just tried your code with `Width="{Binding WidthSize}" Height="{Binding HeightSize}"` set on the `Image` and it works just fine

Comment: Same as dkozl, locally your code seems to be OK. Although the XAML you've posted here is missing `GridView` tags around the `GridViewColumns`.

Comment: hmm thats really weird because it works only if i set the width and height manually in xaml code without any binding.. I also checked the xaml code everything is fine just the binding doesnt work

Comment: You clearly have something else interfering with your `Binding`. Try to recreate and simplify your problem in another project or application and you will soon find your error.